# AR(2) simulation with arima.sim()

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I am trying to understand how `arima.sim` works. I simulated an AR(2) process and computed the values manually. If I specify 2 starting innovations, then it is clear how `arima.sim` computes the third value and on. But it is not clear to me, how the function computes the first two values. Here is a minimal working example.

```
Phi<-c(0.2,0.5)
n.start<-length(Phi)
model<-list(ar=Phi)
n<-10
start.innov<-c(1,4)
set.seed(1121)
innov<-rnorm(n=10)
arsim12<-arima.sim(model=model,n.start=n.start,n=n,start.innov=start.innov,innov=innov)
```

It is clear how the third observation is computed (and the fourth and fifth...)

```
arsim12[3]
[1] 1.462733
sum(rev(Phi)*arsim12[1:2])+innov[3]
[1] 1.462733
```

I would expect the first observation in the time series to be computed similarly, based on start.innov:

```
sum(rev(Phi)*start.innov)+innov[1]
[1] 1.444958
```

But this is different then the first observation:

```
arsim12[1]
[1] 1.484958
```

Any insights ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time series is generated as such:

```
e <- c(start.innov, innov)
x <- filter(e, Phi, "recursive")
```

and then remove the first `n.start` values.

`x` satisfies:

```
x[i] = Phi[1] * x[i - 1] + Phi[2] * x[i - 2] + e[i]
```

Yes, this is just standard AR(2) but if `x[i - 1]` and `x[i]` are indexed by negative or zero, they give 0 (*originally NA for out-of-bound indexing but recoded to 0*). In this way, we see that

```
x[1] = e[1] = 1
x[2] = Phi[1] * x[1] + e[2] = 4.2
x[3] = Phi[1] * x[2] + Phi[2] * x[1] + e[3] =  1.484958
......
```

Finally:

```
arsim12 <- x[3:12]
```

---

As a comparison, your calculation is assuming the first value from `MA(2)`, not `AR(2)`:

```
x[3] = Phi[1] * e[2] + Phi[2] * e[1] + e[3] = 1.444958
```